# How to validate input from edit text with integer

Tags: java, android, authentication

I am newbie to android programing , currently am designing an app to display table from second activity.For that i made a edit text view and create a button to link second activity. can anyone tell me how to set condition while clicking button to check weather text input with integer declared in main activity, if the input matches then it have to go to second activity...

//my function

```
ImageButton btn_go = (ImageButton) findViewById(id.login_user_roll);
    btn_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           Log.i("clicks", "You Clicked B1");
            if (findViewById(id.rollnumber).equals(num)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        Student.class);
               startActivity(i);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking for "PRESSED" from [MouseEvent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html) event. Try to follow [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) tutorial